# How to find the first 5 values (including nans) after first non nan value detected in pandas data frame row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

If I have a Pandas DataFrame like this:

```
     0   1   2    3    4    5    6    7
 A  NaN NaN NaN   1    2    5    6    2
 B  NaN NaN NaN   2   NaN   1   NaN   3
 C   5   4   3    2    1    5    9    1
 D   6   2  NaN   5    1    3    5   NaN
 E  NaN NaN  6    2    1    3    5    1
```

How do I find the first five values after a non NaN value such that I get a Pandas data frame like this:

```
     0    1    2    3    4    
 A   1    2    5    6    2
 B   2   NaN   1   NaN   3
 C   5    4    3    2    1    
 D   6    2   NaN   5    1
 E   6    2    1    3    5
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way using `idxmax` and `all`

```
df.loc[:,df.notnull().all().idxmax():]
   3    4  5    6    7
A  1  2.0  5  6.0  2.0
B  2  NaN  1  NaN  3.0
C  2  1.0  5  9.0  1.0
D  5  1.0  3  5.0  NaN
E  2  1.0  3  5.0  1.0
```

Update

```
pd.DataFrame([df.iloc[i,x:].tolist() for i,x in enumerate(df.notnull().idxmax(1))]).iloc[:,:5]
     0    1    2    3    4
0  1.0  2.0  5.0  6.0  2.0
1  2.0  NaN  1.0  NaN  3.0
2  5.0  4.0  3.0  2.0  1.0
3  6.0  2.0  NaN  5.0  1.0
4  6.0  2.0  1.0  3.0  5.0
```

Comment: That doesn't accomplish entirely what OP wants.  I don't know of a pandas/numpy solution, but reconstructing the df with a list comp would work.